# How do I migrate to and seed to a test database with knex?

Tags: knex.js

I am trying to migrate to a test database using Knex. Currently all the knex migrations and seeds appear to use development environment as defined in my `knexfile.js`:

```
╭─x@x-MBP ~/Desktop/prog/biblion ‹create-lists●› 
╰─$ npx knex migrate:latest
Using environment: development
Already up to date
```

That all works fine for the dev db but I need to point them to my test database for the purposes of testing. I am not sure where to set up this logic though.

Here is my knexfile.js:

```
/**
 * @type { Object.<string, import("knex").Knex.Config> }
 */
module.exports = {
  test: {
    client: 'postgresql', //how does the postgres client know where to look?
    connection: {
      database: 'bibliontest',
      user: 'x',
      password: 'xx',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
  },

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'biblion',
      user: 'x',
      password: 'xx',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
  },
[...]
```

I am not sure what other parts of my codebase to show to rectify this issue. I'd appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay finally worked it out.

For migrations

```
knex migrate:latest --env test
```

For seeds:

```
 knex seed:run --env test
```